# Getting input param from controller in Joomla 3 vs. 4

Tags: joomla-4.x, jinput

When doing this in a frontend controller:

```
class MyControllerCustom extends BaseController
{
    public function __construct($config = array())
    {
        parent::__construct($config);

        print_r($this->input->get('id'));
        ...
    }

}
```

and calling it like this:

```
index.php?option=com_mycomp&task=custom.hello&id=777
```

In Joomla 3 i get 777. Fine.

In Joomla 4 i get the Article ID the home menu link is bound to. Joomla 4 puts the whole menu item including the ID into the input structure.

Is that how it should work? How to get the get parameter in Joomla 4 directly without messing Joomla 4 with menu item stuff around?

I could focus on getting it like this:

```
$id = $this->input->get->get('id', 0);
```

But that's kind of lazy.

This is no router issue.